# List of Crazyhouse engines

Tags: engines, chess-variants, crazyhouse

I want to get a list of all (because they are certainly only a few existing) crazyhouse engines. I searched in lichess forum posts by googling "crazyhouse engine" and collected many names and links from 3 different posts.

Initial list, to complete:

[Sunsetter](http://sunsetter.sourceforge.net/)

[Stockfish](https://en.lichess.org/forum/team-crazyhouse-engine-development-and-game-analyses/stockfish-playing-crazyhouse?page=1) (a well known engine, recently implemented for crazyhouse, seems to be the strongest for this variant in this thread, is the default used in lichess for crazyhouse, [important news: has beaten jann lee consistently in informal match in this playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-09pBUCdduLOlOZQwwfdZUBaVcgEPuB3))

[Sjeng](https://sjeng.org/indexold.html)

[Tjchess](http://tonyjh.com/chess/tjchess/)

[Immortal](https://sites.google.com/site/deuteriumengine/files/crazyhouse)

[nebiyu](https://sites.google.com/site/dshawul/home)

[pulsar](http://www.lanternchess.com/pulsar/)

[sjaak](http://www.eglebbk.dds.nl/program/chess-download.html)

[Crazyhouse by nathanlo99](https://github.com/nathanlo99/Crazyhouse)

Comment: KKFChess: http://web.archive.org/web/20160305200546/http://freespace.virgin.net/andrew.fankk/

Comment: Crazyhouse by nathanlo99: https://github.com/nathanlo99/Crazyhouse

Comment: so now lichess and chess.com will be full of engine-using accounts playing crazyhouse :(

Comment: @CashCow I mean, we shouldn't stop talking about engines just because there are cheaters. They can be detected and the information about them benefits both the cheater and the mods, so I don't see how this will induce more cheating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [computer list of the Crazyhouse Chess Variant Association](https://sites.google.com/site/zhassociation/computer-zh-engine):

- [Sjeng](https://sjeng.org/indexold.html)
- [KKFchess](http://web.archive.org/web/20160305200546/http://freespace.virgin.net/andrew.fankk/)
- [Pulsar](http://www.lanternchess.com/pulsar/)
- [Nebiyu Alien](https://sites.google.com/site/dshawul/home)
- [Imortal](https://sites.google.com/site/deuteriumengine/files/crazyhouse)
- [Sjaak](http://www.eglebbk.dds.nl/program/chess-download.html)
- [TJchess](http://tonyjh.com/chess/tjchess/)
- [TSCP zh](http://www.tckerrigan.com/Chess/TSCP/Community/)
- [Sunsetter](https://github.com/georgvonzimmermann/Sunsetter)
- [CrazyWa](http://hgm.nubati.net/)

And aside from that there is the [multi-variant Stockfish](https://github.com/ddugovic/Stockfish) that plays Crazyhouse.

And [Crazyhouse by nathanlo99](https://github.com/nathanlo99/Crazyhouse)

Comment: In the comments of the question post says more engines, look please!

Comment: I accept to thank you but you should complete your answer with my post and comments.

Comment: @Santropedro Which one did I miss?

Comment: The second comment on the post says this one: Crazyhouse by nathanlo99: github.com/nathanlo99/Crazyhouse

Comment: @Santropedro Included.

Comment: Do we know which re the strongest?

Comment: @theonlygusti I don't have actual data, but most likely https://github.com/ianfab/Fairy-Stockfish is the strongest at this point